# MariaDb docker container fails on run, why?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, mariadb

Docker logs:

[image: 1]

I use the powershell script to run the container:

```
docker rm ctnr-mariadb --force
docker pull mariadb:latest
docker run --name ctnr-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -e MARIADB_USER=user -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=password -e MARIADB_DATABASE=repo -p 1234:3306 -detach mariadb -v sql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql
```

inside init.sql there is a following script

```
`CREATE TABLE `Contacts` (
  `Id` bigint(20) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `Name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`Id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_general_ci;`
```

My aim is just to initialize a maria db container with some sql scripts bootsrapping database and tables.
i have no idea what to do based on the log messages.

Comment: Please format scripts in your questions and answers to make them more readable. This time I did it for you. https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Comment: It looks like you have the `-v` option after the image name, which makes it a command-line option for the container and not a Docker mount option.  You don't seem to have included the actual startup logs in the question, though, just an image link; if there's more than the argument order, can you [edit] the question to include the actual logs as plain text?

Comment: @KonradBotor thank you, it is my first question on stack overflow.

Comment: @DavidMaze sorry don't have the logs anymore, that is all logs which were in the logs window of docker desktop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your SQL-File is not a file to configure the mariadb instance. You can split up your commands like the following code snippet:

```bash
docker rm ctnr-mariadb --force
docker pull mariadb:latest
docker run --name ctnr-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -e MARIADB_USER=user -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=password -e MARIADB_DATABASE=repo -p 1234:3306 -detach mariadb
docker exec -i ctnr-mariadb sh -c 'exec mariadb -uroot -pexample repo' < ./sql/init.sql
```

Attention: I have hard coded the environment variables in the last command.

Comment: Thank you, your solution works. It doesnt execute as a powershell script but works as a .bat.

Answer (score 0):

As per `docker run` [documentation](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/) all Docker arguments must be placed before the image name. Everything after the image name is a command to be run inside the image (equivalent to CMD in Dockerfile).

With that in mind your `docker run` command should be:

```
docker run --name ctnr-mariadb -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=example -e MARIADB_USER=user -e MARIADB_PASSWORD=password -e MARIADB_DATABASE=repo -p 1234:3306 --detach -v sql/init.sql:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/init.sql mariadb
```